# Refactor and Improve Query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, caching

**Outlet.rb**:

```
def latest_reports
  weekly_reports.limit(10)
end
```

**Outlet_controller.rb**:

```
@all_outlets = Outlet.includes(:weekly_reports)
@search = @all_outlets.search(params[:q])   # load all matching records
@outlets = @search.result.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
```

**outlet/index.slim**:

```
- @outlets.each do |outlet|
  tr
    td= link_to outlet.name, outlet_path(outlet)
    th
      ul.reports
        li class="#{'done' if outlet.monitored_today}"
    th
      ul.reports
        - for report in outlet.latest_reports
          li class="#{'done' if report.quota_met}"= report.times_monitored
```

I'm not sure why, but this loads it up as several different queries. I'm pretty sure it's because the include in my controller isn't correct (because I'm using a method in the model).

If anyone could help me improve this, I would be extremely grateful :).

**Note:** I'm developing on PostgreSQL

**Update:**: Posted the full controller action.

Comment: can u share your model code with relation

Comment: In your view you use `@outlets` but in your controller you set `@all_outlets`, is it what do you want?

Comment: I'm using the gem 'ransack' to search, but I've just updated that above now so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Seems like your search gem messes something, so try to move `includes(:weekly_reports)` to `@search.result.includes(:weekly_reports).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])`. This will do the same thing if I'm wrong, or fix the problem if I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 3 at least, if you use

```
Model1.includes :model2
```

then the result is one query for each model.  You can access instances of the associated model from the result and no extra queries will be made.

If you really want it all in one query, you can do this:

```
Model1.joins(:model2).includes(model2)
```

This will produce a nice long JOIN query that loads all the data for both models in one go.  Rails will populate the result with instances of both models already loaded.

So, you should be able to replace

```
@all_outlets = Outlet.includes(:weekly_reports)
```

with

```
@all_outlets = Outlet.includes(:weekly_reports).joins(:weekly_reports)
```

and it should combine everything into one query.

Comment: As you can see above in my controller, I am using an include to JOIN with the table weekly_reports. However, in only one query I want to get an outlet, and fetch the last 10 weekly_reports associated with it.